# 1password ansible script for login and edit the password

Tags: templates, ansible, ansible-template, 1password

My aim to auto login and edit the password.

Tried this script

```
---
- name: Get device information
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars:
    one_pass_signinaddress: "https://xxxxx.1password.com"
    one_pass_emailaddress: "xxxx@xxxxx.com"
    one_pass_secretkey: "xxxxxxyyy"
    one_pass_master_password: "xxxxx"


  tasks: 
    - name: Login one_pass
      shell: "op signin {{ one_pass_signinaddress }} {{ one_pass_emailaddress }} {{ one_pass_secretkey }} {{ one_pass_master_password }} --output=raw"
      register: op_session
    
    - name: Edit Password
      shell: op edit item "Test" password=qweqwe23424
      register: op_edit
```

Its gives this error

```
accepts at most 3 arg(s), received 4
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://support.1password.com/command-line-getting-started/), it looks like you don't pass your secret key and password on the commandline, just the URL and your email address. Then it will prompt you for the secrets. I haven't used the tool myself, let alone via Ansible, so I can't offer a solid approach to get it to work, but it might be possible using the `stdin` argument on the `shell` task or otherwise using an `expect` script.